# How to find current version of Firebase Firestore in Xcode

Tags: xcode, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to figure out what version of Firebase Firestore I'm using without using Cocoa pods. Is there anyway to do this purely through Xcode? I know that I have some version of Firestore downloaded as I can see it in the 'frameworks, libraries and embedded content' section, I'm just not sure how to access the version number in Xcode.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It should be listed next to the package name under "Package Dependencies" of the project navigator. [image]

Comment: There's no mention of Firestore here. Does the version number of Firebase also encompass Firebase Firestore?

Comment: check out their source code: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk 
You'll notice that Firestore is one of the file directory folders under their repo which pushes out a new release periodically for the entire Firebase SDK repo.